# How to achieve blurred background visual effect

Tags: android

Please do you know how to achieve this effect (blur on the background) in Android?

[image: HTC WildFire shutting down]

My HTC WildFire does this when is about to be turned off

Comment: I don't program android apps, but my first guess is taking a screenshot and then blurring it. Not sure if it's possible to take a screenshot as a normal program, or if that requires special privileges.

Comment: My SonyEricsson also does it. And fortunately I do program Android apps :-D   Mostly its a confirm dialog box, and most of the confirm dialog boxes will bring the same effect if your HTC has modified the base UI of Android version being used.

Comment: I know how to make a confirm dialog like that, but the background is not effected in any way (by default)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I googled for "android blur background" and found [this blog post](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-blurring-and-dimming-background-windows-from-dialogs/). Basically:

```
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this). /*... setTitle and so on ...*/ ;

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=0.0f;  // this sets the amount of darkening
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```