# android: how to take a screenshot and blure it?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make sort of a custom dialogue, which would have a previous screen(shot) as a background, a bit darkened and blurred, as if out of focus.

To do this, I guess, when the dialog is initiated, a screenshot should be taken, made darker, blurred and placed as a background for the dialogue...

What do you think would be the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This is conceptually straightforward, but with some potential difficulties.  Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: at first, how do I capture that screenshot?

Comment: Of your own app or of someone else's?  Have you tried searching stack overflow?

Comment: @Roger - you probably want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211451/cool-visual-effect-when-an-htc-phone-is-turning-off

Comment: Hmm... not really. "dialog.getWindow()..." gives "The method getWindow() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder" ... any ideas?

Comment: @Roger - you're probably not using well the Builder. In the example in that question I cut that out, but a common pattern is to call: `new AlertDialog.Builder(this).set..().set...().create();`, which sets various parameters and then returns an `AlertDialog`, which *has* `getWindow()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one way, merely a trick, for blurring, that you can try easily. First downscale Bitmap to, say half the size, and then upscale it back to original size using filtering. I have no idea how this turns out though.

Here's brief code example using this idea. The smaller you scale the original bitmap, the more 'blurred' should it get. But based on a few experiments it becomes very much pixelated if you use smaller than half the size using this technique. More than I was expecting.

```
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width / 2, height / 2, true);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

Rect scaledRect = new Rect(0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight());
Rect origRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, scaledRect, origRect, paint);
paint.setColor(Color.argb(80, 0, 0, 0));
canvas.drawRect(origRect, paint);
```

Last two lines draw a semi-transparent black overlay over the Bitmap making it darker. Also [BlurMaskFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlurMaskFilter.html) was not much a go as it works only on alpha channel. Unfortunately. Or maybe I just missed something in its usage.

Comment: Hmm... not really. "dialog.getWindow()..." gives "The method getWindow() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder" ... any ideas?

Comment: What I was after is [View.draw(Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29). Don't know if it works in your case, but as said, this is something I've never played around with.